# Unreliable iPad car connection cable

Tags: ipad, accessories, sound-volume, car-integration

I own a 2008 Scion (made by Toyota) which has a built-in port for connecting iPod/iPhone/iPad to the car's stereo for audio and remote control. I purchased the recommended adapter cable which connects the car's console to the the 30-pin connector on my iPad 3. ([Link to interface cable PT546-21062 by Toyota](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004E5MBG8))

After a week or so, it started losing the connection if the iPad moved, so I started sliding the iPad between the seat and the center console to keep it still. This worked as long as I didn't bump it.

Starting this week, going around a turn has been enough to cause the connection to completely fail even when the iPad is held in place. I've noticed the end of the adapter plugged into the iPad easily wiggles back to front.

How can I be sure the problem is the cable and not my iPad?

I can still connect the iPad to my computer using the 30-pin to USB cable that came with my iPad, but that only uses 5 or 6 of the 30-pins the cable supports. I also unscrewed the console in the car and checked that the internal wiring there is all solid.

What would be the best way to try to fix this? Are there 30-pin extension cables that have more sturdy connectors that would lock into the port on my iPad better?

Is this something I could get help with at the Apple Store or would they not help since the adapter is made by Toyota rather than Apple?

Comment: I found a friend who also had an iPhone with the 30-pin connector and his didn't work in my car either so I ordered a new adapter cable from Amazon. Should be here tomorrow and I'll post the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing with a friend's iPhone I replaced the cable an it is working now. The connection feels tighter than the old one did even when it was new, so the old one may have just been defective.